# How can I spy on X client messages?

Tags: x11, icons

In an evergoing battle against [an ugly icon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39471/how-can-i-change-the-battery-icon-in-the-systray), I found that applications can communicate with the [system tray](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html#messages) by sending X client messages. Is there a utility for spying on these messages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the application under [xtrace](http://xtrace.alioth.debian.org/). It'll log all communications between the application and the X server, including the command to send or receive an X client message.

```
xtrace myapp
```

Comment: That's kind of what I'm trying to solve - what application is putting that there? I have the class window class name: `gnome-power-manager`, but there is no aplication called that. There is nothing matching "*power*" running as a daemon.

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff Trace the server side, i.e. the system tray.

Comment: Oh, and are you sure that the communication is via window events and not via dbus?

Comment: @ShawnJ.Goff `gnome-power-manager` is nowadays part of `gnome-settings-daemon`

Answer (score 5):

Command

```
    xev -id WINDOW_ID
```

will print X11 "window events". In X11, these things are called "events". (As opposed to "messages" in Microsoft Windows).

To obtain window id, use xwininfo.

man xev, man xwininfo.

Comment: A [client message][1] seems to be a type of event. The freedesktop [system tray spec][2] specifically talks about an "x client message".

In any case, I have the correct window, but `xev` is not giving my any information about what program is sending what event to that window, but its status is definitely being updated by something.


[1]: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/client-communication/client-message.html
[2]: http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html#messages